# Contact form send to selected email from dropdown

Tags: php, forms

I know this has been asked before however I did not understand the answers given and/or could not find a way to make it work for myself. I simply want the message from my contact form to be sent to whoever is chosen in the drop down selection on the form page.

Note: I am very new to this.

HTML

```
  <form method="post" action="contact.php">
        <br>
           <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="35" autocomplete="off" minlength="1" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <br>
           <select name="to" placeholder="Select One" required>
              <option value="Select One" disabled selected> --- Send to --- </option>
              <option value="p1">person 1</option>
              <option value="p2">person 2</option>
              <option value="p3">person 3</option>
           </select>
        <br>
           <input name="email" type="email" maxlength="35" autocomplete="off" minlength="1" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <br>
           <textarea name="message" maxlength="350" minlength="20" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <br>
     <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        <br>
  </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$from = $_POST["name"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$subject = "New message from" . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$email_from);

echo '<br><center><p>Your message has been sent.</center>';
?>
```

Comment: The person selection of your form looks good (assuming you're using actual email addresses in those option values), but where is your `$subject` coming from?

Comment: have you configured your php.ini to send email?  Here is a tutorial outlining the things you need to do for that: https://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Comment: @nathan check if the below code of mail ,mail("someone@example.com","My subject","WORKS!");

Comment: Yay 1 more free relay for spammers!

Comment: @user1760150 Yes, there is no issue with my server sending mail, but like the post says, I don't know how to have the form send the content to the selected person.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm sorry, I forgot to remove that, it isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for your wonderful input and detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $headers = "Reply-To:  <info@xyz.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: Team <info@xyz.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: Team <info@xyz.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Organization: Team\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";                                
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n"; 

    $sent = mail( $to,$email_subject,$message,$headers);
```

Instead of just passing $from pass that information in **headers** Hope this helps

Comment: Im not sure how this solves my issue though? I just need the form data to be emailed to the selected person on the form...